# ¿Como eliminar registros de la base de datos de acuerdo a las relaciones de tablas?

Tags: mysql

Espero se encuentren bien.

Lo que sucede es lo siguiente, estoy desarrollando una aplicación web sencilla para un colegio y estoy trabajando con una base de datos relacional como se observa en la imagen adjunta.

En mi aplicación web acceden varios usuarios (Funcionarios, Docentes, Padres, Estudiantes) y cada uno tiene un rol diferente, por ende distintas funcionalidades. Por ejemplo, los estudiantes sólo consultan notas, los docentes actualizan notas, los funcionarios pueden crear y eliminar usuarios en la base de datos; aquí se plantea mi interrogante, **¿cómo controlo el tema de la eliminación de usuarios en las tablas teniendo en cuenta las relaciones que poseen las mismas?**, por ejemplo, si un funcionario desea eliminar el usuario de un padre debería eliminar primero el registro de un estudiante que pertenece a dicho padre, tomando en cuenta la teoría de relación de tablas padres e hijas debido a las llaves primarias y foráneas.

Eso es lo que no sé, pues pienso que no sería correcto escribir un mensaje en pantalla diciendo al funcionario, primero debes eliminar el registro del estudiante para eliminar el del padre. Quisiera saber que sería lo más apropiado para estos casos o si debo reformular las relaciones de las tablas.

Disculpen por escribir tanto y les agradezco mucho.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Primero, la relación que planteas está mal, tu tabla padre es la de alumnos y la secundaria en todo caso es la de los Padres, eventualmente puedes eliminar un padre y actualizar el id del mismo en la tabla de alumnos. Ahora, lo importante: ¿Por qué baja física? Hoy por hoy no hay casi motivos para hacerlo: ¿Es muy caro el costo de almacenar unos bytes más? ¿Es enorme la penalidad de performance en la BD por mantener algunos registros más? ¿Vale la pena "romper" la "historia" del sistema? Sugerencia: baja lógica con una columna Habilitado (1/0) y lo controlas desde la aplicación. Saludos.

Comment: Como dijo Patricio Moracho, lo mejor es agregar una columna más al usuario con flag en donde debería estar o no dado de baja. Lo otro que puedes hacer es eliminar en cascada pero esas declaraciones van en el *foreign key*.

Comment: Otra sugerencia/comentario, ¿por que tantas tablas que apuntan básicamente a lo mismo? Acaso los docentes, empleados y alumnos no son Personas? ¿Por que no una única tabla de Personas con otra tabla de relación de estas con sus Tipos? Piensa que una persona podría ser eventualmente las tres cosas, en distintos momentos o incluso en un mismo período, ¿son tres personas distintas o es la misma que cumple distintos roles en distintos momentos?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que yo siempre hago es poner la relacion `ONDELETE en restric` y `ONUPDATE en cascade` los usuarios (docentes,alumnos,..etc) deben de tener un campo `status` con valor 0 o 1 que indique si esta eliminado o no. Esto para evitar eliminar y que los datos nunca se pierdan, al momento de eliminar un alumno simplemente haces un `update status = 0`